# Computation of Chromatic number

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

What little i know is that a discrete graph and an empty graph has chromatic number $1$, while a complete graph with $n$ vertices has a  chromatic number $n$. I am curious to know whether there is any known formula to calculate the chromatic number of a simple graph $G$ just by knowing its number of vertices ( order) and number of edges (size)? Any  reference (if possible) in this regards would also be appreciated.

Comment: no. consider 4 vertices with 3 edges. one possibility is a triangle and an isolated vertex, which has chromatic number 3. another possibility is a square with 3 out of 4 sides, which has chromatic number 2

Comment: Try Googling "chromatic number"

Answer (score 1):

The problem of finding the chromatic number of a graph in general in an NP-complete problem.

https://www2.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall05/cps230/L-24.pdf (see the last page)

So there is no general formula to calculate the chromatic number based on the number of vertices and edges. There are a number of *types* of graphs for which we know the chromatic number (e.g., cycles), and we know a number of bounds on the chromatic number (both upper and lower). But there is no known formula based only on vertices and edges.

Comment: That "so" is very weird. The fact that chromatic number is not merely a function of # of vertices and edges is WAYYYYY easier than proving that finding the chromatic number is an NP-complete problem